# What does "behaviorism sentiment" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have heard a professor say:

> The behaviorism sentiment is uncommon within this academy.

It is not clear to me.  I could take it to mean that some people within this academy are sympathetic to this theory, not yet rationally committing to, or that some have become followers of behaviorism.

So what does the professor actually mean?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are getting confused over the meaning of *sentiment*.  In addition to a feeling or emotion, it can also mean:

> **sentiment** |ˈsen(t)əmənt|
>
> noun
>
> **1** a view of or attitude toward a situation or event; an opinion: I agree with your sentiments regarding the road bridge.
>
> - general feeling or opinion: the council sought steps to control the rise of racist sentiment.
> - archaic the expression of a view or desire esp. as formulated for a toast.

(source: NOAD)

Given this, I believe the professor means simply that ideas from the school of *behaviorism* are uncommon in the academy about which he is talking.